# Wireless network card drivers

Tags: wireless, networking

I was wondering if drivers are available for the Linksys WMP300n wireless network card for Ubuntu?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and run:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

Is your device this? `14E4:4329` If so, it is a Broadcom wireless device. Please open Software and Updates and make sure that main, universe, restricted and multiverse are enabled. A window will open asking you to reload; accept and continue.

With a temporary working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should be working.

If your device ID is different, edit your question to include it and I will propose a solution.

Comment: :-)  Luckily both of your telepathy antennas are still working because my right telepathy antenna has broken off and the OP was too far away from me to link directly to his computer.  ;-)